# Why is Shaak Ti considered the "clone mom?"

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

This is a bit of a looser question, but I'm fairly certain it has a solid answer.

It's well known in Star Wars that Plo Koon is the "clone dad" of the Jedi, as he has a couple episodes in TCW where he is shown to be explicitly caring for the clones in ways that the other Jedi aren't, prioritizing them as more than just fighters.  But I've noticed people referring to Shaak Ti as being the "clone mom" of the Jedi, and I can't remember any episodes or scenes in TCW where she had any interactions with her clones at all.

Is there any canon-base for Shaak Ti being the "clone mom?"  In a certain TCW episode or a comic?  Or is this just a cute fan-theory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first episode of *The Clone Wars* Season Three, "[Clone Cadets](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_Cadets)", Shaak Ti is shown as the Jedi responsible for overseeing the final combat training of the clones before they are accepted as troopers. Her interactions show she cares for them, and is unwilling to cast them aside, even if they are failing, and provides gentle encouragement when they come talk to her. In the next episode, "[ARC Trooper](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/ARC_Troopers)s" she's shown commanding the defense of Kamino and fighting alongside the clones to defend the younger ones and the embryos.

So yeah, pretty much Clone Mom.

Comment: Oh my gosh, the cadet episodes!  I forgot about those!  Thanks so much; that makes total sense!

Comment: Also, in the Bad Batch premier, some clones on Kamino are shown escorting a gantry with Shaak Ti's body on it.

Comment: @SpyBoxOnline Oh, was that confirmed to be Shaak Ti's body?  How do we know?

Comment: It wasn't confirmed it was her as far as I know, and the (brainwashed) clones didn't show any particular reaction in any case. They were just hauling around dead bodies for disposal. Only Hunter was shown as being troubled as he watched.

Comment: Ah okay, I was wondering if the lightsaber was explicitly confirmed to be Shaak Ti's.  I couldn't tell if it had any identifying features.

Comment: I just assumed it was Shaak Ti because she was the only jedi on Kamino, because she oversaw the clones. It wasn't confirmed but I don't know who else it could be.